Can I define a function in KQL that takes a table with all its columns as input, uses only 2 mandatory columns and outputs again all columns?
My following KQL function takes a table as input and joins it with another table on the "name" column in order to perform additional transformations afterwards.
How can I define the function so that I don't lose any of the tables columns? For the transformations only the columns "name" and "value" are mandatory, but I still want to keep all other columns in the resulting table.
Here is my function:
.create-or-alter function with (docstring = "decode hex-strings from table", folder = "jobs") decode_hex_from_table(T:(name:string, value:string), _output_tablename:string) {
    let statistics_configs = database("statistics").statistics_configs | project name=src_name, description, value_type, start_byte, num_elements, element_length, little_endian, factor;
    let jobs_decoded = materialize(
        T
        | join kind=leftouter statistics_configs on name
        |  (...more transformations)
        );
  table(_output_tablename)
 }

If I don't mention the "name:string" column as input (and just type "T:(*)"), I can't perform the join on it. But I also can't just add ", *" to the input columns...
In the future I want to apply the function to various tables with differing column names (whilst "name" and "value" will always be present).

The function accepts tables with varying column names but requires "name" and "value" columns for transformations. It achieves this by dynamically selecting all columns from the input table, ensuring the "name" and "value" columns are included, and then performing a left outer join using these columns. Finally, it materializes the resulting table, preserving all original columns, and can be used for various tables with differing column names.

Thank you Balaji, I don't understand how I could not see this!
